# SimpleGeo - Obtaining the Longitude and Latitude from response

Tags: .net, json.net, simplegeo

I have the following response in JSON format, but, can't seem to figure out how to obtain the logitude and latitude from it

I tried

```
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(response.Content)
```

but when I try to obtain an an item with the key "address"...I get nothing

here is the JSON response

> {"query":{"latitude":37.779278,"longitude":-122.416582,"address":"San
>   Francisco,
>   CA"},"timestamp":1311197030.697,"features":[{"handle":"SG_4oR6CqYUXZVEotM8ncLk80_37.780722_-122.417364","name":"06075012400","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-122.421050,37.775147,-122.413365,37.784657],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_4oR6CqYUXZVEotM8ncLk80_37.780722_-122.417364.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"US
>   Census","type":"Region","subcategory":"Tract"}]},{"handle":"SG_6qya2EVo227KTsivPoqx28_37.782005_-122.420177","name":"Civic
>   Center","license":"Not For
>   Redistribution","bounds":[-122.425482,37.773229,-122.409979,37.790629],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_6qya2EVo227KTsivPoqx28_37.782005_-122.420177.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Neighborhood","type":"Region","subcategory":null}]},{"handle":"SG_2TnIHbITsDUjuLyhbVeYgx_37.779398_-122.419353","name":"94102","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-122.429920,37.769441,-122.404583,37.789226],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_2TnIHbITsDUjuLyhbVeYgx_37.779398_-122.419353.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Postal
>   Code","type":"Region","subcategory":null}]},{"handle":"SG_4gzxFRgOF9YjFAtAiQFpDC_37.793367_-122.397153","name":"Assembly
>   District
>   13","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-122.546386,37.708230,-122.281780,37.929824],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_4gzxFRgOF9YjFAtAiQFpDC_37.793367_-122.397153.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Legislative
>   District","type":"Region","subcategory":"Provincial
>   (Lower)"}]},{"handle":"SG_2WBEyBsRAqLAHw1QuqXTv1_37.787198_-122.429550","name":"Congressional
>   District
>   8","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-122.612285,37.708131,-122.281780,37.929824],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_2WBEyBsRAqLAHw1QuqXTv1_37.787198_-122.429550.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Legislative
>   District","type":"Region","subcategory":"National"}]},{"handle":"SG_7TAYWdlPlAIzUDT7MVwxmZ_37.759717_-122.693971","name":"San
>   Francisco","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-123.173825,37.639830,-122.281780,37.929824],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_7TAYWdlPlAIzUDT7MVwxmZ_37.759717_-122.693971.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Administrative","type":"Region","subcategory":"County"}]},{"handle":"SG_1mNfKHr5aXH7LWgmZL8Uq7_37.759717_-122.693971","name":"San
>   Francisco","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-123.173825,37.639830,-122.281780,37.929824],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_1mNfKHr5aXH7LWgmZL8Uq7_37.759717_-122.693971.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Municipal","type":"Region","subcategory":"City"}]},{"handle":"SG_4wyrIh6TQId1MiL2cfYa5d_37.759717_-122.693971","name":"San
>   Francisco Unified School
>   District","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-123.173825,37.639830,-122.281780,37.929824],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_4wyrIh6TQId1MiL2cfYa5d_37.759717_-122.693971.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"School
>   District","type":"Region","subcategory":"Unified"}]},{"handle":"SG_4n4ze6xOdAFr0gp1WboZrN_37.551206_-122.127401","name":"San
>   Francisco","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-122.516667,37.191667,-121.733333,38.041667],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_4n4ze6xOdAFr0gp1WboZrN_37.551206_-122.127401.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Urban
>   Area","type":"Region","subcategory":null}]},{"handle":"SG_1wm1YKOa9HLv5VI8IbHVW7_38.107525_-122.693633","name":"State
>   Senate District
>   3","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-123.134523,37.708230,-122.281780,38.532067],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_1wm1YKOa9HLv5VI8IbHVW7_38.107525_-122.693633.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Legislative
>   District","type":"Region","subcategory":"Provincial
>   (Upper)"}]},{"handle":"SG_2MySaPILVQG3MoXrsVehyR_37.215297_-119.663837","name":"California","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-124.482003,32.528832,-114.131211,42.009517],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_2MySaPILVQG3MoXrsVehyR_37.215297_-119.663837.json","abbr":"CA","classifiers":[{"category":"Subnational","type":"Region","subcategory":"State"}]},{"handle":"SG_3tLT0I5cOUWIpoVOBeScOx_41.316130_-119.116571","name":"America/Los_Angeles","license":"creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/","bounds":[-124.733253,32.534622,-114.039345,49.002892],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_3tLT0I5cOUWIpoVOBeScOx_41.316130_-119.116571.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"Time
>   Zone","type":"Region","subcategory":null}]},{"handle":"SG_3uwSAEdXVBzK1ZER9Nqkdp_45.687160_-112.493107","name":"United
>   States of
>   America","license":"http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/","bounds":[-179.142471,18.930138,179.781150,71.412180],"href":"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_3uwSAEdXVBzK1ZER9Nqkdp_45.687160_-112.493107.json","abbr":null,"classifiers":[{"category":"National","type":"Region","subcategory":null}]}],"weather":{"wind_speed":"6.9
>   meters per
>   second","temperature":"78F","dewpoint":"59F","cloud_cover":"0%","wind_direction":"325
>   degrees","forecast":{"tonight":{"conditions":"Mostly
>   cloudy","precipitation":"0%","temperature":{"max":"58F","min":"55F"}},"tomorrow":{"conditions":"Clear","precipitation":"0%","temperature":{"max":"70F","min":"56F"}},"today":{"conditions":"Clear","precipitation":"0%","temperature":{"max":"73F","min":"59F"}}},"conditions":"Clear"},"demographics":{"population_density":7489},"intersections":[{"distance":38.43225250350512,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.4167858,37.779583799999997]},"properties":{"highways":[{"osm_way_id":"33789567","type":"residential","name":"Fulton
>   Street"},{"osm_way_id":"26988030","type":"tertiary","name":"Larkin
>   Street"}],"attribution":"(c) OpenStreetMap (http://openstreetmap.org/)
>   and
>   contributors","license":"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/"},"type":"Feature","id":"65287204"},{"distance":69.25254468826954,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.4165794,37.778655200000003]},"properties":{"highways":[{"osm_way_id":"26988030","type":"tertiary","name":"Larkin
>   Street"},{"osm_way_id":"8920461","type":"unclassified","name":"Grove
>   Street"}],"attribution":"(c) OpenStreetMap (http://openstreetmap.org/)
>   and
>   contributors","license":"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/"},"type":"Feature","id":"65354417"},{"distance":139.2095933887024,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.41696140000001,37.780493499999999]},"properties":{"highways":[{"osm_way_id":"27167270","type":"residential","name":"McAllister
>   Street"},{"osm_way_id":"26988030","type":"tertiary","name":"Larkin
>   Street"}],"attribution":"(c) OpenStreetMap (http://openstreetmap.org/)
>   and
>   contributors","license":"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/"},"type":"Feature","id":"65352337"},{"distance":139.9292506517826,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.415127,37.779789000000001]},"properties":{"highways":[{"osm_way_id":"8915763","type":"residential","name":"Fulton
>   Street"},{"osm_way_id":"26988009","type":"tertiary","name":"Hyde
>   Street"}],"attribution":"(c) OpenStreetMap (http://openstreetmap.org/)
>   and
>   contributors","license":"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/"},"type":"Feature","id":"65287201"},{"distance":152.92687955288244,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.4149213,37.778867400000003]},"properties":{"highways":[{"osm_way_id":"26988009","type":"tertiary","name":"Hyde
>   Street"},{"osm_way_id":"8920461","type":"unclassified","name":"Grove
>   Street"}],"attribution":"(c) OpenStreetMap (http://openstreetmap.org/)
>   and
>   contributors","license":"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/"},"type":"Feature","id":"65360267"}],"address":{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-122.41670097091016,37.77925384607872],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"address":"164
>   Larkin St","distance":"0.01","postcode":"94109","city":"San
>   Francisco","county":"San
>   Francisco","province":"CA","country":"US"},"type":"Feature"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I would expect there to be a key called "query" which returns another dictionary.  That would have keys for longitude and latitude.

```
Dim queryDict = result.Item("query")
Dim lng = queryDict.Item("longitude")
Dim lat = queryDict.Item("latitude")
```

Excuse the syntax, but I haven't done .net/VB for ages, so have no idea if that's right.

It might also help you if visualise the JSON you've got.  Try pasting it in to this tool and clicking the render button:
http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm